# how to use visual studio c++ debugger?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++

(i was just working on visual studio c++, and my program breaks at some point. and debugger starts. which points to an specific err location. in this case it was easy to rebuild the binary file.)

i want to see each and every thread of the process, then what is the process to use it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you reword the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about the running application's threads is available in the Threads window.

For example, here's what the Threads window looks like after I've broken into an application with the debugger that creates only a single thread:

[image: Sample application, showing Threads window with only a single thread]

You can find more information about how to use the Threads window [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx).